# Unable to remove phpstorm background

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I'm using phpStorm for my Symfony2 project, And I'm getting this "not found" message probably for all methods. so I have 2 questions.

1) Why phpStorm can't find my methods?

2) How to remove this annoying background from "not found" methods?

Screenshot is here:

[image]

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

Often PhpStorm cannot guess the type. You can help it by using typehints:

```php
public function indexAction(Request $request);
```

phpdocblocks:

```php
/**
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) {return new Response('');}
```

and inline comments:

```php
/* @var \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form */
$form = $this->createForm(/* ... */);
```

For Symfony, there's an excelent plugin you can install and very much improve your experience with PhpStorm and the Symfony framework: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=phpStorm

It supports all bunch of features, including autocompletion of container services.

As for the "annoying background", look into PhpStorm color settings. You can configure pretty much anything in there, including changing the theme if you don't like the default one.

Comment: Jakub, Thanks for your response. I will test that plugin.
I have checked phpStorm apperience settings for removing that background color, but I was unable to find anything.

Thanks again!